# how to implement filter Search using Struts2 Jquery Plugin

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to implement filter search for my Struts2 jquery grid.  If I search any string (through jquery filter textbox) then it is calling my action class but i am unable to get the search string in my action class.
 I tried to print this line inside my Action class but the Search String is not appearing in my Action class.

```
System.out.println("This line is getting printed But search textbox values is not printing."+searchString+""+searchField);
```

Please help me for this, i tried a lot ,and still am trying for it..
**My Code:**

Subjectinfo.jsp

```
            <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
            <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
            <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%> 
            <%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%> 
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Hello World</title> 
            <style type="text/css">
            @import
            url(<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/style1.css);
            </style> 
             <sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="le-frog"/> 
            </head>
            <body> 
                <div id="setpage"> <s:url id="editurl" action="nedit"/>
                    <s:url id="editurl" action="nedit"/>
                    <s:url  id="remoteurl" action="ntable"/>

                    <sjg:grid
                       id="gridtable"
                        caption="Customer Examples"
                        dataType="json"
                        filter="true" 
                        filterOptions="{ stringResult :true, 
                        searchOnEnter : false, 
                        enableClear : true, 


                        gridModel="gridModel"
                        rowList="10,15,20"
                        navigatorDelete="true">
                    <sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="subjectId" title="ID" formatter="integer" sortable="true" key="true" 
                                       search="true" searchoptions="{sopt:['eq']}" editable="true"  hidden="true"   />

                    <sjg:gridColumn name="subjectName" index="subjectName" title="Subject Name" sortable="true" search="true"
                                        editable="true"
                                        edittype="text" />
                    </sjg:grid> 

                    </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching

When the stringResult option is set to true the data posted to the server is a string and the structure of the posted data is the same as in Advanced Search.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options

So I think your problem is that you are looking for searchString, but the jqgrid is sending a request variable called filters, which is a json string as described in the advanced search options link.